# Exporting single table to PDF using AmCharts

Tags: amcharts, html-to-pdf

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/35076c4d7b6eef7764dacc61f72adadc

In the tutorial above, they are exporting a number of AmChart graphs and then converting them to PDF;
Here is the problem I am facing right now:
I want to export single table into PDF using AmCharts export function. 
However, the next lines of code seem to not work

```
chart["export"].toPDF(layout, function(data) {
this.download(data, "application/pdf", "amCharts.pdf");
});
```

Is there a way to export the table into PDF using AmCharts .toPDF() function?

Comment: PDFMake, which AmCharts uses, doesn't support HTML but you can create a table using their object structure and add it to the layout. You can see this in lines 331-345 in the codepen you linked to where it's adding a table by pushing a table object into the layout.